# Input field for selecting multiple filters value in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, filter, pivot-table

I recently started going into more details and learning about Excel VBA but this one is giving me issues.

On one sheet I have 6 Pivot Tables - they are using the same data source, each one has specific (different) combination of filters set but really the only filter that I need to change on regular basis on each of them is "Country Name", e.g. "Germany", "United Kingdom", "Italy" etc.

Is there any way I can add one text field in which I would enter desired country name and button next to it which will, upon calling, set "Country Name" filters on all of the pivots to entered text field value? If possible, it would be great to add RefreshAll function after the filter values have been updated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use a Slicer instead? http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/slicers.html

Comment: Which version of Excel? If 2010, or later, yes a slicer is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a Slicer, Pivot Tables -> Analyze -> insert Slizer.
Then connect the Slizer too the other PT by clicking on the Slizer -> Slizer Tools -> Option -> Report Connections and selecting the Pivot Tables.

Comment: Wow, never thought it was that simple! And without coding! Worked like a charm, thanks!